# How to quickly change classes twice on one button click

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

What I'm trying to do:
Make a transition between Link pages in React, so when one clicks on a nav button, a slider animation pops in from the right, quickly slides over the window, and then back, in one swift motion, and then goes to the next page.

What I've tried:
A lot. Before I was trying to use a useState function, but couldn't figure out how to make it switch back to the original class, or remove the class. Currently I have this.

```
const sliderHandler = () => {
  const slider = document.getElementById('slider');
  slider.addClass('slider-close');
  setTimeout(RemoveClass, 1000)
}
function RemoveClass() {
  slider.removeClass('slider-close')
} 

/More Code/

    <div id="slider" ></div>
```

Styles

```
#slider {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-color: #202c3f;
  transition: all .4s ease-in-out;
  z-index: 1001;
}

@keyframes slide {
  0%   {width: 0vw;}
  40%  {width: 100vw;}
  60%  {width: 100vw;}
  100%   {width: 0vw;}
}

.slider-close {
  transition: all .1s ease-in-out;
  animation-name: slide;
  animation-duration: 0.4s;
}
```

In the above code I'm trying to make it so on button click, it adds the class .slider-close, waits, and then removes it. When I attempt it comes up with either "slider.addClass is not a function" or "slider is null".

This seems like a simple function that I just cannot wrap my head around, sp any help appreciated.

Comment: `.addClass` is a jquery function. You should use `classList.add` and `classList.remove`

Comment: That did it, thanks so much. Didn't realize I didn't have JQuery on there, I usually do on my projects. If you want to submit it for the answer I'll approve it.

Comment: Good idea of a slider transition :)  You can also try `classList.toggle`.